# How do I make my app compatible with older Android versions with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I had a web app but decided to go Android, so I'm using Cordova but having a hard time making my app compatible with old Android versions (4.4), (5.0), and (5.1). It works on 6.0+ tho.

We are using HTML, CSS, Javascript, Polymer, and Firebase for our development. We set our minimum API level as 19 and target API level as 27 and noticed that Android versions prior to 6.0 are not working. People can download and install our app, but their screen goes blank after the splash image when you open the app.

We tried using Crosswalk, which technically worked but had poor navigation performance, so we ditched them. We want an option that is functionally like Crosswalk but uses a newer chromium version.

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well i´ve got bad news for you you either have to go with crosswalk or use a webcomponent [polyfill](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/polyfills) both wont be performing well. This old browser can´t handle webcomponents well.

Answer (score 0):

The hard truth: Remove use of Polymer.

This might not be the answer you like (nor what the moderators might like), but it will solve your problem.

Also, avoid using most of what was added in CSS3. I've personally had to "cripple" CSS due to external requirements for broadest possible support for Android.

Also, use Inspect to your advantage, notably Console and Network, to see what goes on.